# Can get this CodePen to run locally

Tags: rangeslider

https://codepen.io/danielmdesigns/pen/rWqbam#code-area

My code is below, but it does not work on the local browser. What am I missing?
I can not figure out what do to in order for this to work locally.

I appreciate the help of anyone. I want this range slider to be on my website soon.

My code is below, but it does not work on the local browser. What am I missing?
I can not figure out what do to in order for this to work locally.

I appreciate the help of anyone. I want this range slider to be on my website soon.

My code is below, but it does not work on the local browser. What am I missing?
I can not figure out what do to in order for this to work locally.

I appreciate the help of anyone. I want this range slider to be on my website soon.

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    
//slider javascript
/*! rangeslider.js - v2.0.2 | (c) 2015 @andreruffert | MIT license | https://github.com/andreruffert/rangeslider.js */
! function(a) {
  "use strict";
  "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["jquery"], a) : a("object" == typeof exports ? require("jquery") : jQuery)
}(function(a) {
  "use strict";

  function b() {
    var a = document.createElement("input");
    return a.setAttribute("type", "range"), "text" !== a.type
  }

  function c(a, b) {
    var c = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return setTimeout(function() {
      return a.apply(null, c)
    }, b)
  }

  function d(a, b) {
    return b = b || 100,
      function() {
        if (!a.debouncing) {
          var c = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
          a.lastReturnVal = a.apply(window, c), a.debouncing = !0
        }
        return clearTimeout(a.debounceTimeout), a.debounceTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
          a.debouncing = !1
        }, b), a.lastReturnVal
      }
  }

  function e(a) {
    return a && (0 === a.offsetWidth || 0 === a.offsetHeight || a.open === !1)
  }

  function f(a) {
    for (var b = [], c = a.parentNode; e(c);) b.push(c), c = c.parentNode;
    return b
  }

  function g(a, b) {
    function c(a) {
      "undefined" != typeof a.open && (a.open = a.open ? !1 : !0)
    }
    var d = f(a),
      e = d.length,
      g = [],
      h = a[b];
    if (e) {
      for (var i = 0; e > i; i++) g[i] = d[i].style.cssText, d[i].style.display = "block", d[i].style.height = "0", d[i].style.overflow = "hidden", d[i].style.visibility = "hidden", c(d[i]);
      h = a[b];
      for (var j = 0; e > j; j++) d[j].style.cssText = g[j], c(d[j])
    }
    return h
  }

  function h(a, b) {
    var c = parseFloat(a);
    return Number.isNaN(c) ? b : c
  }

  function i(a) {
    return a.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + a.substr(1)
  }

  function j(b, e) {
    if (this.$window = a(window), this.$document = a(document), this.$element = a(b), this.options = a.extend({}, n, e), this.polyfill = this.options.polyfill, this.orientation = this.$element[0].getAttribute("data-orientation") || this.options.orientation, this.onInit = this.options.onInit, this.onSlide = this.options.onSlide, this.onSlideEnd = this.options.onSlideEnd, this.DIMENSION = o.orientation[this.orientation].dimension, this.DIRECTION = o.orientation[this.orientation].direction, this.DIRECTION_STYLE = o.orientation[this.orientation].directionStyle, this.COORDINATE = o.orientation[this.orientation].coordinate, this.polyfill && m) return !1;
    this.identifier = "js-" + k + "-" + l++, this.startEvent = this.options.startEvent.join("." + this.identifier + " ") + "." + this.identifier, this.moveEvent = this.options.moveEvent.join("." + this.identifier + " ") + "." + this.identifier, this.endEvent = this.options.endEvent.join("." + this.identifier + " ") + "." + this.identifier, this.toFixed = (this.step + "").replace(".", "").length - 1, this.$fill = a('<div class="' + this.options.fillClass + '" />'), this.$handle = a('<div class="' + this.options.handleClass + '" />'), this.$range = a('<div class="' + this.options.rangeClass + " " + this.options[this.orientation + "Class"] + '" id="' + this.identifier + '" />').insertAfter(this.$element).prepend(this.$fill, this.$handle), this.$element.css({
      position: "absolute",
      width: "1px",
      height: "1px",
      overflow: "hidden",
      opacity: "0"
    }), this.handleDown = a.proxy(this.handleDown, this), this.handleMove = a.proxy(this.handleMove, this), this.handleEnd = a.proxy(this.handleEnd, this), this.init();
    var f = this;
    this.$window.on("resize." + this.identifier, d(function() {
      c(function() {
        f.update()
      }, 300)
    }, 20)), this.$document.on(this.startEvent, "#" + this.identifier + ":not(." + this.options.disabledClass + ")", this.handleDown), this.$element.on("change." + this.identifier, function(a, b) {
      if (!b || b.origin !== f.identifier) {
        var c = a.target.value,
          d = f.getPositionFromValue(c);
        f.setPosition(d)
      }
    })
  }
  Number.isNaN = Number.isNaN || function(a) {
    return "number" == typeof a && a !== a
  };
  var k = "rangeslider",
    l = 0,
    m = b(),
    n = {
      polyfill: !0,
      orientation: "horizontal",
      rangeClass: "rangeslider",
      disabledClass: "rangeslider--disabled",
      horizontalClass: "rangeslider--horizontal",
      verticalClass: "rangeslider--vertical",
      fillClass: "rangeslider__fill",
      handleClass: "rangeslider__handle",
      startEvent: ["mousedown", "touchstart", "pointerdown"],
      moveEvent: ["mousemove", "touchmove", "pointermove"],
      endEvent: ["mouseup", "touchend", "pointerup"]
    },
    o = {
      orientation: {
        horizontal: {
          dimension: "width",
          direction: "left",
          directionStyle: "left",
          coordinate: "x"
        },
        vertical: {
          dimension: "height",
          direction: "top",
          directionStyle: "bottom",
          coordinate: "y"
        }
      }
    };
  j.prototype.init = function() {
    this.update(!0, !1), this.$element[0].value = this.value, this.onInit && "function" == typeof this.onInit && this.onInit()
  }, j.prototype.update = function(a, b) {
    a = a || !1, a && (this.min = h(this.$element[0].getAttribute("min"), 0), this.max = h(this.$element[0].getAttribute("max"), 100), this.value = h(this.$element[0].value, this.min + (this.max - this.min) / 2), this.step = h(this.$element[0].getAttribute("step"), 1)), this.handleDimension = g(this.$handle[0], "offset" + i(this.DIMENSION)), this.rangeDimension = g(this.$range[0], "offset" + i(this.DIMENSION)), this.maxHandlePos = this.rangeDimension - this.handleDimension, this.grabPos = this.handleDimension / 2, this.position = this.getPositionFromValue(this.value), this.$element[0].disabled ? this.$range.addClass(this.options.disabledClass) : this.$range.removeClass(this.options.disabledClass), this.setPosition(this.position, b)
  }, j.prototype.handleDown = function(a) {
    if (a.preventDefault(), this.$document.on(this.moveEvent, this.handleMove), this.$document.on(this.endEvent, this.handleEnd), !((" " + a.target.className + " ").replace(/[\n\t]/g, " ").indexOf(this.options.handleClass) > -1)) {
      var b = this.getRelativePosition(a),
        c = this.$range[0].getBoundingClientRect()[this.DIRECTION],
        d = this.getPositionFromNode(this.$handle[0]) - c,
        e = "vertical" === this.orientation ? this.maxHandlePos - (b - this.grabPos) : b - this.grabPos;
      this.setPosition(e), b >= d && b < d + this.handleDimension && (this.grabPos = b - d)
    }
  }, j.prototype.handleMove = function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();
    var b = this.getRelativePosition(a),
      c = "vertical" === this.orientation ? this.maxHandlePos - (b - this.grabPos) : b - this.grabPos;
    this.setPosition(c)
  }, j.prototype.handleEnd = function(a) {
    a.preventDefault(), this.$document.off(this.moveEvent, this.handleMove), this.$document.off(this.endEvent, this.handleEnd), this.$element.trigger("change", {
      origin: this.identifier
    }), this.onSlideEnd && "function" == typeof this.onSlideEnd && this.onSlideEnd(this.position, this.value)
  }, j.prototype.cap = function(a, b, c) {
    return b > a ? b : a > c ? c : a
  }, j.prototype.setPosition = function(a, b) {
    var c, d;
    void 0 === b && (b = !0), c = this.getValueFromPosition(this.cap(a, 0, this.maxHandlePos)), d = this.getPositionFromValue(c), this.$fill[0].style[this.DIMENSION] = d + this.grabPos + "px", this.$handle[0].style[this.DIRECTION_STYLE] = d + "px", this.setValue(c), this.position = d, this.value = c, b && this.onSlide && "function" == typeof this.onSlide && this.onSlide(d, c)
  }, j.prototype.getPositionFromNode = function(a) {
    for (var b = 0; null !== a;) b += a.offsetLeft, a = a.offsetParent;
    return b
  }, j.prototype.getRelativePosition = function(a) {
    var b = i(this.COORDINATE),
      c = this.$range[0].getBoundingClientRect()[this.DIRECTION],
      d = 0;
    return "undefined" != typeof a["page" + b] ? d = a["client" + b] : "undefined" != typeof a.originalEvent["client" + b] ? d = a.originalEvent["client" + b] : a.originalEvent.touches && a.originalEvent.touches[0] && "undefined" != typeof a.originalEvent.touches[0]["client" + b] ? d = a.originalEvent.touches[0]["client" + b] : a.currentPoint && "undefined" != typeof a.currentPoint[this.COORDINATE] && (d = a.currentPoint[this.COORDINATE]), d - c
  }, j.prototype.getPositionFromValue = function(a) {
    var b, c;
    return b = (a - this.min) / (this.max - this.min), c = Number.isNaN(b) ? 0 : b * this.maxHandlePos
  }, j.prototype.getValueFromPosition = function(a) {
    var b, c;
    return b = a / (this.maxHandlePos || 1), c = this.step * Math.round(b * (this.max - this.min) / this.step) + this.min, Number(c.toFixed(this.toFixed))
  }, j.prototype.setValue = function(a) {
    a !== this.value && this.$element.val(a).trigger("input", {
      origin: this.identifier
    })
  }, j.prototype.destroy = function() {
    this.$document.off("." + this.identifier), this.$window.off("." + this.identifier), this.$element.off("." + this.identifier).removeAttr("style").removeData("plugin_" + k), this.$range && this.$range.length && this.$range[0].parentNode.removeChild(this.$range[0])
  }, a.fn[k] = function(b) {
    var c = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return this.each(function() {
      var d = a(this),
        e = d.data("plugin_" + k);
      e || d.data("plugin_" + k, e = new j(this, b)), "string" == typeof b && e[b].apply(e, c)
    })
  }
});

//custom slider javascript
var $element = $('input[type="range"]');
var $handle;

$element
  .rangeslider({
    polyfill: false,
    onInit: function() {
      $handle = $('.rangeslider__handle', this.$range);
      updateHandle($handle[0], this.value);
    }
  })
  .on('input', function() {
    updateHandle($handle[0], this.value);
  });

function updateHandle(el, val) {
  el.textContent = " " + "$" + val + " ";
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  
  //when slider changes, hide start message
$("input").on("change", function() {
  $("#helper").fadeOut("slow");
});

//promo-box
$("#js-promo-box").hide();
$("#promo-link").on("click", function(){
  $("#js-promo-box").slideToggle();
  return false;
});
  
});
```

```css
//SLIDER
$lighter-blue: #abe0ed
$light-blue: #46b7d5
$blue: #0085b2
$orange: #FD8521
$lightgray: #cccccc

main
  width: 70%
  margin: 8rem auto 0

h1
  font-weight: 800
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif
  color: $light-blue
.min
  padding-top: 5px
  padding-left: 10px
  color: $lightgray
.max
  padding-top: 5px
  padding-right: 10px
  color: $lightgray
#helper
  //float: left;
  //display: inline-block
  padding-top: 40px
  color: $light-blue
  font-style: italic
output
  display: inline-block
  font-size: 2em

/* original css */
.rangeslider,
.rangeslider__fill
  display: block
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
  -moz-border-radius: 10px
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px
  border-radius: 10px

.rangeslider
  background: #e6e6e6
  position: relative

.rangeslider--horizontal
  height: 20px
  width: 100%

.rangeslider--vertical
  width: 20px
  min-height: 150px
  max-height: 100%

.rangeslider--disabled
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=40)
  opacity: 0.4

.rangeslider__fill
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, $lighter-blue , $light-blue) /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, $lighter-blue, $light-blue) /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, $lighter-blue, $light-blue) /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, $lighter-blue , $light-blue) /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
  position: absolute
.rangeslider--horizontal .rangeslider__fill
  top: 0
  height: 100%
.rangeslider--vertical .rangeslider__fill
  bottom: 0
  width: 100%

.rangeslider__handle
  background: white
  color: $blue
  font-weight: bold
  font-size: 18px
  border: 1px solid #ccc
  cursor: pointer
  display: inline-block
  width: 100px
  height: 40px
  line-height: 38px
  text-align: center
  position: absolute
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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')
  background-size: 100%
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)))
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1))
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1))
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1))
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
  -moz-border-radius: 22px
  -webkit-border-radius: 22px
  border-radius: 22px
.rangeslider__handle:after
  font-family: FontAwesome
  content: "\f0da"
  color: $lightgray
.rangeslider__handle:before
  font-family: FontAwesome
  content: "\f0d9"
  color: $lightgray

.rangeslider__handle:active
  background-img: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,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")
  background-size: 100%
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12)))
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12))
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12))
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12))
.rangeslider--horizontal .rangeslider__handle
  top: -10px
  touch-action: pan-y
  -ms-touch-action: pan-y
.rangeslider--vertical .rangeslider__handle
  left: -10px
  touch-action: pan-x
  -ms-touch-action: pan-x

input[type="range"]:focus + .rangeslider .rangeslider__handle
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.9)
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.9)
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.9)
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- font awesome -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/FontAwesome.otf">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/css/animations.css">


<main>
<input type="range" value="6500" step="25" min="1000" max="12600">

<div class="range">
  <small class="min pull-left">Min</small>
  <small class="max pull-right">Max</small>
</div>

  <p id="helper" class="slideRight text-center"><small>Slide to get started &#x2192</small></p>
  
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS code you pasted is in **SASS** format, you need to compile it first. It looks like you are also missing some JavaScript code there. Try to see the compiled content in Codepen's page.

Answer (score 0):

When you look your pen in detail mode, you have a cool button "resources" that show every external link to css and js files of the pen... make sure to copy both of them to your local code in the right order :)